# Graduated Filter with Lightroom to adjust Whites and Blacks

Tags: lightroom, lightroom-5

I am using Lightroom and I am finding it pretty easy.  I'm able to use Graduated Filter with ease as well.

There is one thing in one of my photos that I would like to touch up, but only for part of the image.  I adjusted the Darks/Lights of the entire photo to make it look more real and to get it the way I like it.  However, in doing this adjustment, I lost a little but of white cloud detail in the sky.

I tried to to a graduated filter on just the sky, but it doesn't give me the option to adjust Darks and Lights on the graduated filter (i only seem to be able to do this for the whole photo).  Is there anyway I can do this?  I tried other adjustments, like exposure, etc on the graduated filter, but it just doesn't get to how I want it to look.  I need to adjust Lights/Darks here.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try adjusting contrast, highlights and shadows.  That will work to change the shape and contrast in the graduated filter areas.